Skip a task that contains a loop
Ansible documentation states that a when condition is executed for every item in a loop.
But, is there a "task global" condition (i.e. when the when clause is false, the whole task is skipped)?

There is no "task global" condition, indeed, but you can easily skip a task that contains a loop if the list you are looping on is empty.
So, if you bake your condition right into your templated loop variable, for example, with an inline if, then you can achieve your desired behaviour.
For exemple:
- name: Skip the whole task
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ range(1,5) if not should_skip else [] }}"
  vars:
    should_skip: true

Which produce the output:
TASK [Skip the whole task] ****************************************
skipping: [localhost]


Also mind that filters like select, reject, selectattr and rejectattr could help you filter down your list to a possibly empty one based on conditions.

This is, based on needs, arguably cleaner than
- name: Skip the whole task
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ range(1,5) }}"
  when: not should_skip
  vars:
    should_skip: true

Producing
TASK [Skip the whole task] ****************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=1) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=2) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=3) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=4) 
skipping: [localhost]


thanks! indeed, this way I was thinking too, but I was "arguing" with chatgpt about "task global skip", and it was so sure about its answer that I began to have my doubts :-P
so, it's time to clean up some roles, because the "when" clause is useless (actually superfluous), loop or with_ clause is all I need

Use the "global" condition to provide an empty list if false. For example, the play
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_list: [a, b, c]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ when_global | d(true) | bool | ternary(my_list, []) }}"

gives (abridged) by default
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
TASK [debug] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=a) => 
  msg: a
ok: [localhost] => (item=b) => 
  msg: b
ok: [localhost] => (item=c) => 
  msg: c

If you set when_global=false the whole task is skipped
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e when_global=false
  ...
TASK [debug] ********************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

The bool filter converts the strings provided by --extra-vars in the INI format.
